# Use the same partials for two controllers in two different folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two controllers like this:

app/controllers/collection_controller.rb:

```
class CollectionController < ApplicationController
    def create
      @collection = Collection.new(name: params[:name])
      @collection.save!
      render @collection
    end
end
```

And an inherited class:

app/controllers/enterprise/collection_controller.rb:

```
class Enterprise::CollectionController < ::CollectionController
    def create
      @collection = Collection.new(name: params[:name])
      @collection.company = Company.find(params[:company])
      @collection.save!
      render @collection
    end
end
```

I have two partials:

app/view/collections/_collection.json.jbuilder:

```
json.extract! collection, :title, :description
json.users do
    json.partial! collection.user
end
```

app/view/collections/_user.json.jbuilder:

```
json.extract! user, :name, :surname
```

The problem is:

When I load `Enterprise::CollectionController#create`, I get `missing template app/views/enterprise/collections/_collection ...`.

I want Enterprise::CollectionController to use `app/view/collections/_collection.json.jbuilder` instead of `app/view/enterprise/collections/_collection.json.jbuilder`.

I tried to do something like:

```
render @collection, partial: 'collections/collection', but I receive:
```

But I receive:

```
missing template for ... app/views/enterprise/users/_user ...
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

After you changed your render partial to

```
render @collection, partial: 'collections/collection'
```

you are not getting an error for `collection` partial. you are getting an error for `user` partial. You will have to change the way you are rendering user partial to

```
json.partial! "collections/user", user: collection.user
```

**Update:**

you can try [append_view_path](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/append_view_path/class). So basically you will append to the default search locations

```
class Enterprise::CollectionController < ::CollectionController
   before_filter :append_view_paths
   def append_view_paths
      append_view_path "app/views/collections"
   end
end
```

So rails will search in `app/views/enterprise/collections, app/views/shared, app/views/collections` in order

You can also use `prepend_view_path` if you want rails to search in `app/views/collections` first

PS: I haven't tested this.

Comment: Uhm... I understand. Isn't there a way to configure `render` to use `app/views` instead of `app/views/enterprise` as main path? So if I'll add more partial, I have to write down `json.partial! "collections/partial_name", var_name: @var` instead of simply `json.partial! @var`

Comment: It's not working for me :( Actually rails can find `app/views/collections/_collection`, but it can't find `app/views/users/_user`...